# How do you display the Disqus comment count in two places on the same page/post?

Tags: comments, disqus

I placed the Disqus comment count in two separate places on my post pages. One comment count is below my post title and the other is in a floating div off to the left of my post body. The comment count only appears one time (only in the floating div to the left of my post body).

I never realized one, for lack of a better term, cancels the other one out. I know there are some scripts that can only be "placed" once on a page. Could Disqus be that kind of script??!!

Or, am I doing something wrong? If so, what should I do to get BOTH comment counts to be displayed on the same post page?

Can't post the link to my site -- work in progress.

Please let me know. Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: I've got the same problem.  This may be a bug in their script, because it only started happening a while ago.  It was working fine when I originally wrote this code.

Comment: Today I noticed the comment counts switched places; meaning the one that was displaying isn't showing and the one that was not showing is now displaying. It was working just fine a few hours before it started happening. When I look at other websites with the same layout, that is to say, 2 comment counts, both are displaying. Now what am I doing wrong?! Argh! Heh, thanks for that, though. Makes me feel somewhat better. Blush.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have the `count.js` script on your page, it will find and replace all links that either:

a. End with `#disqus_thread` in the href tag

b. Have a valid `data-disqus-identifier` attribute value (this corresponds with the `disqus_identifier` if you set one)

If that's the case, you may want to check out the placement on the page itself and make sure `count.js` loads after those links have been rendered.

These concepts are explained in some more detail here: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624

Comment: I've done everything by the book and to the letter, nothing seems to be working. I added '#disqus_thread' to my href tags. This never happened before. I'm seeing some strange things on my other blogs, as well. My comment counts are disappearing then reappearing then only appearing every other post on my homepage. I know disqus is updating their commenting system -- maybe it's got something to do with it? Both blog templates are different so it's weird it's happening in both. I contacted disqus, they pretty much said the same thing and sent the same link. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: I was having the same problem and it wasn't that the comment counts were getting canceled out, it was that trailing slashes are required on your links.  This page summarizes the answer nicely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582847/disqus-comment-count-always-0-comments